# Facebook OG tags - FB debug says they're in Body, but they ain't

Tags: wordpress, facebook, meta

Helping out with a friend's non-profit's Wordpress website....

I have set OG tags for FB shares, but they're not working correctly. When I check them at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ I'm told "Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree. Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable."

But when I view the page source, these tags are ***not*** in the body, they are in the head like they should be. So I'm stumped (not a developer).

site is www.stopgarviespoint.com

Answer (score 1):

You are including the Facebook stuff even before the `<html>` tag. That will throw any HTML parser off.

Put them inside of the `<head>` section (just like Facebook says).

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
<!--- PUT IT HERE --->
```